# LWC in Flow screen not retaining default property values

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

I am trying to embed a LWC with lot of configurable properties in a Flow. Most of the properties need to have default values to start with so that user spends less time configuring the component.
However, when the screen renders, the default values are not retained at all. Has anybody else faced a similar issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to set the defaults in your component's configuration file. Flow does not yet support the default attribute on the Property element in the LWC configuration file. To use defaults with Flow, set them in your code and not in your configuration file.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for letting us know about this limitation. May I ask, are there any plans in the near-mid term to support this? We're building many custom LWCs for Flows, and we'd prefer to avoid setting default values in the code if there are plans to support this in the near future.

Comment: Salesforce is indeed planning to fix this but can't commit to a target date.

Comment: Here's an example of how to set a default value in the .js code: `@api myPropertyColor = 'rgb(0, 112, 210)';`