# Why does the second instance of my wire adapter not work when I am using @api variables?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, screen-flow, flow-screen-component, getpicklistvalues

I am trying to retrieve picklists from two different record types of the object Case by using `getPicklistValuesByRecordType()`. I can accomplish this if i write my code like the following:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValuesByRecordType } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import CASE_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Case';

export default class case_form extends LightningElement {
poolRecordTypeId = '0127Z0000019yq4QAA';
spabadRecordTypeId = '0127Z0000019yq9QAA';

poolPicklistContainer = [];
spabadPicklistContainer = [];

@wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, { objectApiName: CASE_OBJECT, recordTypeId: '$poolRecordTypeId' })
populatePoolPicklistContainer({ error, data }) {
    this.poolPicklistContainer = data ? data.picklistFieldValues : [];
    if(error) console.log('Error: ', error);
};

@wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, { objectApiName: CASE_OBJECT, recordTypeId: '$spabadRecordTypeId' })
populateSpabadPicklistContainer({ error, data }) {
    this.spabadPicklistContainer = data ? data.picklistFieldValues : [];
    if(error) console.log('Error: ', error);
};
}
```

However, if I change the variables with `@api` only the first `@wire` function works. Why is that and is there something that I could do to fix this?

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValuesByRecordType } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import CASE_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Case';

export default class case_form extends LightningElement {
@api poolRecordTypeId; // <-- Changed code
@api spabadRecordTypeId; // <-- Changed code

poolPicklistContainer = [];
spabadPicklistContainer = [];

@wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, { objectApiName: CASE_OBJECT, recordTypeId: '$poolRecordTypeId' })
populatePoolPicklistContainer({ error, data }) {
    this.poolPicklistContainer = data ? data.picklistFieldValues : [];
    if(error) console.log('Error: ', error);
};

@wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, { objectApiName: CASE_OBJECT, recordTypeId: '$spabadRecordTypeId' })
populateSpabadPicklistContainer({ error, data }) {
    this.spabadPicklistContainer = data ? data.picklistFieldValues : [];
    if(error) console.log('Error: ', error);
};
}
```

The LWC Metadata:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>54.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
            <property name="poolRecordTypeId" label="Case type &#34;Pool&#34; Id " type="String" default="0127Z0000019yq4QAA" required="true"/>
            <property name="spabadRecordTypeId" label="Case type &#34;Spabad&#34; Id " type="String" default="0127Z0000019yq9QAA" required="true"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>

</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show the template thay includes the component, or the component's properties (and the LWC's meta declaration of the target properties). Basically need to see how the two `@api` properties are initialized.

Comment: I updated my question, hope I understood what you asked for. I have noticed that in the first code example each `@wire` runs twice, once before it has gotten any value in the `recordTypeId` param and then again once it has value. In the second example when I use `@api` only the first `@wire` runs twice, the second wire adapter only runs once, without any value in the `recordTypeId`.

Comment: Every wire is always invoked at least once with no error or data. You will find this described in many other wire-related questions' answers here. If you are allowing the target property config defaults to be used (you have not set both values separately when using the component in your flow), note that both have the same value. In this case LWC will optimize the wire executions and only call the server once to cache the value. I am guessing you have found a weird edge case where the attempted concurrent but equal calls are compressed to one but the LWC wire functions are not both called.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Do you know if there is any way to force both functions to be executed or an alternative to using wire to get picklist values of an object by record type id?

Comment: Ensure the parameter combinations for the two are unique (I.e. different) or use imperative apex calls instead of wires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason my code was not working was because the `default` attribute for LWC properties are [not supported in Screen flows](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/297231/112878).

Comment: Comes down to wanting g to initialize the values and ensuring they are different then really... BTW bad idea to default to ID values since these vary across different orgs. Note, however, this is not the only reason for not working, but more that you need the appropriate and distinct values.

Answer (score 3):

Every wire is always invoked at least once with no error or data before being called with the actual data or error info. You will find this described in many other wire-related questions' answers here.

If you are allowing the target property config defaults to be used (i.e. you have not set both values separately when using the component in your flow), note that both have the same value according to your question.

In this case LWC will optimize the wire executions and only call the server once to cache the value.

I am guessing you have found a weird edge case where the attempted concurrent but equal calls are compressed to one but the LWC wire functions are not both called.

To resolve this either ensure the parameter combinations for the two are unique (i.e. different IDs are passed) or use imperative apex calls instead of wires.

BTW, it is a good idea to ensure the defaults/settings from component usage properties are names of values rather than IDs since IDs are not portable.